# Values duplicating when fetching data from database and displaying to ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Im new to Android Developement and currently working on an app that should give me the time between first time clicking a button and second time clicking the button and add it to a currently selected customer.

Current Status of App:
I established a connection to da mySql Database using Volley and a local webservice.

It works to insert my customers and time stamps to the table, but when loading times for a specific customer i get a strange result in one case. I tried debugging it but the app keeps crashing on debugging without a message. When not debugging it doesnt crash but shows weird data.

To the problem:

In my main activity called "ZeitErfassen" i have a button to get an overview of all customers display in a ListView.
I create the Listview with a custom ArrayAdapter because i want to pass my objects to the next Activity where my customers are displayed.

So onCreate of the overview of customers i create a new arraylist and fill it with all customers from my database. this list i pass to my customadapter and then set it as my adapter of the Listview.
Now, when i click on an item, i call a php script and pass the customer_id to the query to fetch all times from database where customer_id = customer_id.

Now the part where i get "strange" data...

1.(Source:ZeitErfassen;Destination:AddCustomer) I create a new customer,example xyz, in the app, data gets passed to the database.

2.(Source:ZeitErfassen;Destination:DisplayCustomer) I call my overview for all customers where the ListView is filled with data as described above. At the end ob the List I see the customer i just created,xyz.

3.Go back to Main Activity(ZeitErfassen)

4.(Source:ZeitErfassen;Destination:DisplayCustomer)I open the overview for all customers again, and it shows my last created user two times! so last entry, xyz, entry before last, xyz!

After that, i can open the view as many times as i want, the customer never gets duplicated again!

The debugger stopps after step 2.

Now when i click on the new customers, it calls the script to fetch the times by customer_id.
One of the xyz entrys display the correct times from database.
The second one, i just found out, display the times where customer_id="". In the database the value for "" is 0.

I have no clue where the second customer suddenly appears from and debugging didnt help me either -.-
When i close the app an open it again, there ist just one entry for the user that was visible twice before closing the app. It doesnt duplicate on opening view...

Here is my code..

Main Activity ZeitErfassen

```
public class ZeitErfassen extends AppCompatActivity {

public static LinkedList<Kunde> kunden = new LinkedList<Kunde>();
boolean running = false;
long startTime,endTime,totalTime;

private SharedPreferences app_preferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private TextView displayTime;
public Button startEndButton;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private Spinner spinner;
public static Kunde selectedCustomer;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zeit_erfassen);
    //Einstellungen laden
    app_preferences =  getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    startTime= app_preferences.getLong("startTime", 0);
    endTime = app_preferences.getLong("endTime", 0);
    running = app_preferences.getBoolean("running", false);
    displayTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zeit_bei_Kunde);
    displayTime.setText((CharSequence) app_preferences.getString("zeitAnzeige", "Zeit bei Kunde"));
    startEndButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_Timer);
    startEndButton.setText((CharSequence) app_preferences.getString("timerButton", "Start Timer"));
    DatabaseHelper.customerFromDatabaseToList(this);
    editor = app_preferences.edit();
    editor.commit();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    editor.putLong("startTime", startTime);
    editor.putString("zeitAnzeige", (String) displayTime.getText());
    editor.putString("timerButton", (String) startEndButton.getText());
    editor.putLong("endTime", endTime);
    editor.putLong("totalTime", totalTime);
    editor.putBoolean("running", app_preferences.getBoolean("running", false));
    editor.commit();
    this.finish();
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
 //   saveCustomers();
 //   createDropDown();
}


public void startTimer(View view) {
    editor = app_preferences.edit();

    if(running == false) {
        startTime = getTime();
        running = true;
        editor.putLong("startTime", startTime);
        startEndButton.setText("End Timer");
        displayTime.setText("Zeitstoppung läuft");
        editor.putString("zeitAnzeige", (String) displayTime.getText());
        editor.putString("timerButton", (String) startEndButton.getText());
        editor.putBoolean("running", true);
        editor.commit();

    } else {
        setSelectedCustomer();
        endTime = getTime();
        editor.putLong("endTime",endTime);
        totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        editor.putLong("totalTime", totalTime);
        displayTime.setText(formatTime(totalTime));
        editor.putString("zeitAnzeige", (String) displayTime.getText());
        startEndButton.setText("Start Timer");
        editor.putString("timerButton", (String) startEndButton.getText());
        running = false;
        editor.putBoolean("running", false);
        editor.commit();
        DatabaseHelper.timeToDatabase(String.valueOf(selectedCustomer.getId()),formatTime(totalTime),this);
    //    selectedCustomer.saveTimeToCustomer(selectedCustomer, formatTimeForCustomer(totalTime));

    }
}

public String formatTime(Long totalTime) {
    int hours   = (int) ((totalTime / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
    int minutes = (int) ((totalTime / (1000*60)) % 60);
    int seconds = (int) (totalTime / 1000) % 60;

    String time = (String.valueOf(hours) + ":" + String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds));
    return time;
}
public String formatTimeForCustomer(Long totalTime) {
    StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year    = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month   = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day     = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    time.append((String.valueOf(year) + "." + String.valueOf(month) + "." + String.valueOf(day))).append(formatTime(totalTime));
    return time.toString();
}

public void  neuerKunde(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddKunde.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void kundenÜbersicht(View view) {
//    setSelectedCustomer();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayCustomer.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public long getTime() {
    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return millis;
}

public void setSelectedCustomer() {
    if(kunden.size() > 0) {
        if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() != null) {
            String tempCustomer = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            for (Kunde k : kunden) {
                if (k.getName().equals(tempCustomer)) {
                    selectedCustomer = k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public void createDropDown() {
    /*File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(),"kunden.ser"); NOT USED BECAUSE DATABASE WORKS
    if(file.exists()) {
        Kunde.importFromFile(this);
    }*/
        if (kunden.size() > 0) {
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.chooseCustomer);
            // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, DisplayCustomer.namesOfCustomers());

            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
}
```

}

DisplayCustomer(Where all customers are displayed with data from Database)

```
public class DisplayCustomer extends AppCompatActivity {
CustomerAdapter customerAdapter;
public ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCustomerView;
private ListView listCustomerView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_customer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ArrayList<Kunde> customerList = getCustomerObjects();
    customerAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(this,customerList);
    listCustomerView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_View_Customers);
    //  adapterCustomerView = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesOfCustomers());
    listCustomerView.setAdapter(customerAdapter);
    openCustomerDetails();
}


public static ArrayList<String> namesOfCustomers() {
    ArrayList<String> customerNames = new ArrayList<>();
    if(ZeitErfassen.kunden.size() > 0 ) {
        for (Kunde k : ZeitErfassen.kunden) {
            customerNames.add(k.getName());
        }
    }
    return customerNames;
}


public static ArrayList<Kunde> getCustomerObjects() {
    ArrayList<Kunde> customerList = new ArrayList<>();
    if(ZeitErfassen.kunden.size() > 0 ) {
        for (Kunde k : ZeitErfassen.kunden) {
            customerList.add(k);
        }
    }
    return customerList;
}


public void openCustomerDetails() {
    listCustomerView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Kunde kunde = new Kunde();
            kunde = (Kunde)listCustomerView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayCustomer.this, DisplayDetailedCustomer.class);
            intent.putExtra("selectedCustomerObject",(Parcelable)kunde);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

My CustomerAdapter to pass data from one intent to another.

```
public class CustomerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Kunde> {
public CustomerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Kunde> customerList) {
    super(context,0,customerList);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Data for this position
    Kunde kunde = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_customer_layout, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCustomerName);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    tvName.setText(kunde.getName());

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

}

DatabaseHelper Class

```
public class DatabaseHelper {
public static RequestQueue requestQueue;
public static String host = "http://192.168.150.238/";
public static final String insertUrl = host+"insertCustomer.php";
public static final String showUrl = host+"showCustomer.php";
public static final String insertTimeUrl = host+"insertTime.php";
public static final String showTimeUrl = host+"showTimes.php";

public static void customerFromDatabaseToList(final Context context)  {
    //Display customer from database
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    final ArrayList<String> customerNames = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray customers = response.getJSONArray("customers");
                if(customers.length() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < customers.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject customer = customers.getJSONObject(i);
                        String customerName = customer.getString("cus_name");
                        String customerAddress = customer.getString("cus_address");
                        int customerID = Integer.valueOf(customer.getString("cus_id"));
                        if (customerName != null && customerAddress != null) {
                            try {
                                Kunde k = new Kunde(customerName, customerAddress, customerID);
                                if (!listContainsObject(k)) {
                                    ZeitErfassen.kunden.add(k);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                showAlert("Fehler in customerFromDatabaseToListn!", "Fehler", context);
                            }
                        } else {
                            showAlert("Fehler in customerFromDatabaseToListn!", "Fehler", context);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

public static boolean listContainsObject(Kunde cust) {
    for(Kunde k : ZeitErfassen.kunden) {
        if(k.getId() == cust.getId()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void timeToDatabase(final String customer_id, final String time_value, final Context context) {
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, DatabaseHelper.insertTimeUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            showAlert("Fehler","Fehler bei Verbindung zur Datenbank",context);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
            parameters.put("customerid",customer_id);
            parameters.put("timevalue",time_value);
            return parameters;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(request);
};



public static void showAlert(String title, String message, Context context) {
    // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
    builder.setMessage(message)
            .setTitle(title);

    // 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
}


public static ArrayList<String> timesFromDataBaseToList(final Context context,final int customer_id) {
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    final String cus_id = String.valueOf(customer_id) ;
    final ArrayList<String> customerTimes = new ArrayList<>();

    StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, showTimeUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                JSONArray times = object.getJSONArray("customertimes");
                if (times.length() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < times.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = times.getJSONObject(i);
                        String timeValue = jsonObject.getString("time_value");
                        if (timeValue != null) {
                            customerTimes.add(timeValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Fehler beim Holen der Zeiten",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
    }){
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
            parameters.put("cus_id",cus_id);
            return parameters;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    return customerTimes;
};
```

}

DisplayDetailedCustomer / Display the times

```
public class DisplayDetailedCustomer extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_detailed_customer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Intent getCustomerParcable = getIntent();
    Kunde customer = getCustomerParcable.getExtras().getParcelable("selectedCustomerObject");

    TextView displayCustomerNameDetailed =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailedCustomerViewName);
    TextView displayCustomerAddressDetailed =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailedCustomerAddress);
    ListView timeListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.detailedTimeListView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DatabaseHelper.timesFromDataBaseToList(this,customer.getId()));
    timeListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    displayCustomerNameDetailed.setText(customer.getName());
    displayCustomerAddressDetailed.setText(customer.getAdresse());
}
```

}

Kunde Class / Customer Class with interface Parcelable

```
public class Kunde implements Serializable,Parcelable {
private String name;
private String adresse;
private int id;
public LinkedList<String> zeiten;

public Kunde(String name, String adresse) throws Exception{
    setName(name);
    setAdresse(adresse);
    zeiten = new LinkedList<String>();
}

public Kunde(String name, String adresse,int id) throws Exception{
    setName(name);
    setAdresse(adresse);
    setId(id);
    zeiten = new LinkedList<String>();
}
public Kunde(){};


public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getId(){
    return id;
}
public void setName(String name) throws Exception {
    if(name != null) {
        this.name = name;
    } else throw new Exception("Name ist ungueltig! in setName");
}

public void setAdresse(String adresse) throws Exception{
    if(adresse != null) {
        this.adresse = adresse;
    }else throw new Exception("Adresse ist ungueltig! in setAdresse");
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getAdresse() {
    return adresse;
}


public void saveZeit(Long totalTime) {
    zeiten.add(String.valueOf(totalTime));
}


public void saveTimeToCustomer(Kunde customer,String time){
   customer.zeiten.add(time);
}

//------------------------------------Parcelable Methods to pass Daata from one Intent to another----------------------------------------
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeString(this.adresse);
//    dest.writeList(this.zeiten);
}
// this is used to regenerate your object. All Parcelables must have a CREATOR that implements these two methods
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Kunde> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Kunde>() {
    public Kunde createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Kunde(in);
    }

    public Kunde[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Kunde[size];
    }
};

// example constructor that takes a Parcel and gives you an object populated with it's values
private Kunde(Parcel in) {
    LinkedList<String> zeiten = null;
    id = in.readInt();
    name = in.readString();
    adresse = in.readString();
}
```

}

Thanks for taking your time!!